# Unable to delete SQL File table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, filestream

We are facing issue in removing SQL Filetable. Whenever I run

```
select * from <MY SQL FILE TABLE>
```

I get this error message

> A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 0 - No process is on the other end of the pipe.)

When I see `sp_readerrorlog`, I see this message

> SQL Server internal error. FILESTREAM manager cannot continue with current command.

When I run this query

```
ALTER DATABASE XXX
REMOVE FILEGROUP FStream1
```

I get this message:

> The filegroup 'FStream1' cannot be removed because it is not empty.

I tried to delete the SQL Filetable

```
drop table `SQLFiletable_bck`
```

but I get this error :

> The FILESTREAM filegroup 'FileStreamGroup1' has no files assigned to it. FILESTREAM data cannot be populated on this filegroup until a file is added.

Then I tried this option

```
ALTER TABLE SQLFiletable_bck 
SET (FILESTREAM_ON = "NULL")
```

but I get this error

> Cannot drop FILESTREAM filegroup or partition scheme since table 'SQLFiletable_bck ' has FILESTREAM columns.

I was not able to drop the SQL File table

Can anyone tell me any way to forcefully cleanup FileStream and its FileGroup in SQL Server 2012?

Answer (score 1):

In order to fix

```
ALTER TABLE TableName SET (FILESTREAM_ON = "NULL")
```

you have to drop the column(s) using FILESTREAM. In order to be able to do that, you probably have to drop some constraint, too:

```
ALTER TABLE TableName DROP CONSTRAINT DF_TableName_ColumnName;
ALTER TABLE TableName DROP COLUMN ColumnName;
ALTER TABLE TableName SET (filestream_on = "NULL");
ALTER DATABASE DatabaseName REMOVE FILE 'DatabaseFileName');
ALTER DATABASE DatabaseName REMOVE FILEGROUP "FilegroupName";
```